# How can a "missing concrete implementation" warning be suppressed?

Tags: dart, warnings

What can I do to prevent the compiler from throwing the following warning

> Missing concrete implementation of setter 'MyClass.field' and getter
>   'MyClass.field'

on the following code?

```
import 'package:mock/mock.dart';

class MyClass {
  String field;
}
@proxy
class MockMyClass extends Mock implements MyClass{}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: shouldn't MockMyClass be an abstract class ?

Comment: For the record: The `@proxy` annotation has no effect in Dart 2. You should no longer use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement `noSuchMethod();` When a class has a `noSuchMethod()` it implements any method. I assume this applies to getter/setter as well because they are just special methods (never tried myself yet though). See also https://www.dartlang.org/articles/emulating-functions/#interactions-with-mirrors-and-nosuchmethod

Comment: the link doesn't work and says "404 Page not found"

Answer (score 6):

The warning comes because you have a class that doesn't implement its interface, and which doesn't *declare* a `noSuchMethod` method.
It's not sufficient to inherit the method, you have to actually declare it in the class itself.

Just add:

```
noSuchMethod(Invocation i) => super.noSuchMethod(i);
```

That should turn off the warning for that class.

Answer (score 0):

About this warning ( [Dart Spec )](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-408.pdf) :

** It is a static warning if a concrete class does not have an implementation for a method in any of its superinterfaces unless it declares its own noSuchMethod method (10.10).
**

So you can create an implementation for getter *`field`* in  your `MockMyClass` class.