# Missing concrete implementation of Getter and Setter

Tags: dart, dart-pub

```
class Shape {
  String color;

  void draw() {
    print('Draw Random Shape');
  }
}

class Rectangle implements Shape {

  @override
    void draw() {
      print('Draw Rectangle');
    }
}
```

**Now the problem is I'm getting a warning saying**

> Missing concrete implementation of getter Shape.color and setter
>   Shape.color

I know that every instance variable in dart has its own getter and setter implicitly.But in case of interface how do I fix this issue.I have also tried to looking at some of the similar questions on the stackoverflow but they'r not helpful.

Comment: Did you try implementing noSuchMethod? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274107/how-can-a-missing-concrete-implementation-warning-be-suppressed

Comment: I can't understand what's the point of implementing noSuchMethod() here.Is this warning a bogus?
@NuruddinIminokhunov

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dart doesn't inherit implementations from `implements Shape`, but only states that `Rectangle` conforms the interface of `Shape`.

You need to add `String color;` to `Rectangle` to satisfy `implements Shape`.
You can do this by adding a field or alternatively a getter and a setter. Both are equivalent from a class' interface perspective.

```
class Rectangle implements Shape {
  String color;

  @override
    void draw() {
      print('Draw Rectangle');
    }
}
```

or

```
class Rectangle implements Shape {
  String _color;

  String get color => _color;
  set color(String value) => _color = value;

  @override
    void draw() {
      print('Draw Rectangle');
    }
}
```

The later is considered bad style if the getter and the setter only forward to a private field with no additional code.

Answer (score 4):

or maybe you just want to `extends` , no need to `implements` ?

you can changes your code into this ?

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';


abstract class Shape {
  String color;

  Shape({
    @required this.color 
  });

  void draw() {
    print('Draw Random Shape');
  }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
  Rectangle() : super(
    color: "#ff00ff"
  );

  @override
    void draw() {
      print('Draw Rectangle');
    }
}
```

hope that can help